# function doesn't work inside ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function in a small library that I have built:

```
HB.FormButtons.inputs = $("input[type='submit'], input[type='button'], button[type='submit'], button.button, .search-button, a.button");
HB.FormButtons.disableFormButtons = function(form) {
    form.find(HB.FormButtons.inputs).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

however I am calling it inside the following:

```
HB.PaymentDetails.deleteSavedCard = function (submittedForm) {
    var cardIdToDelete = submittedForm.find('.deletedCardId').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: submittedForm.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            HB.FormButtons.disableFormButtons($(HB.PaymentDetails.deleteCardFormSelector));
        },
        data: submittedForm.serialize()
    }).done(function(){
        HB.PaymentDetails.deleteSavedCardDoneHandler(cardIdToDelete);
    }).fail(function(xhr){
        HB.PaymentDetails.deleteSavedCardFailHandler(xhr, cardIdToDelete)
    })
};
```

the function inside "beforeSend" doesn't get called, how can I make it work so that it works inside the ajax call as well?

Comment: Anything in console? Errors? Or it just never gets called but ajax call is successful?

Comment: ajax call is successful with no errors,a console.log inside beforeSend gets called too

Comment: try `HB.PaymentDetails.deleteSavedCard = function (submittedForm) {
    var myHB = HB, cardIdToDelete = submittedForm.find('.deletedCardId').val();` and then use `myHB.FormButtons.disableFormButtons($(myHB....)`

Comment: Does HB.FormButtons.inputs have all the elements you expect to see in it?

Comment: yes it does, I think it's do with the fact the form is present in the dom when my script is run

Comment: The current solution I have is to call "form.find(HB.FormButtons.inputs).prop('disabled', true);" directly inside beforeSend